# ruby on rails show page for employee display customers in the same state as the employee logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails and the following is a requirement for an app I am building. 
"The sales person from that geographic area uses the internal portal to review the request and marks the request as being in the qualifying stage"

So basically I want my employee show page to display customers who are already in the system but belong to same state as the employee that is logged in. For example an employee from New York should be able to see all new customers from New York only. So it should only show customers from the geographic location of the employee who is logged in. My login redirects the employee to their show page, which where I want the customer names to be displayed. 
Here is the code for my show page.
I have Customer Request: which should list the customers in same state as the employee. I tried:

```
    <%= @customer.state_id %> but this does not work.
```

Here is my show page code below

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

    <p>
    <strong>First name:</strong>
    <%= @employee.first_name %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <strong>Last name:</strong>
    <%= @employee.last_name %>
    </p>   

      <p>
        <strong>City:</strong>
       <%= @employee.city %>
            </p>

           <p>
      <strong>State:</strong>
      <%= @employee.state.state %>
      </p>

      <p>
      <strong>Role:</strong>
       <%= @employee.role.role %>
      </p>

       <p>
       <strong>Manager:</strong>
       <%= @employee.manager_name %>
       </p>

       <p>
       <strong>Customer Requests:</strong>
        </p>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_employee_path(@employee) %> |
        <%= link_to 'Back', employees_path %>
```

Comment: What does "...but this does not work" mean? What does it do that it should not do? Does it simply print the ID of the state rather than the name of the state?

Answer (score 0):

Please post schema and model, without these, it's hard to guess.

Basically, your schema should have tables for User, Addresses and Roles. In your case, employee and customer are both users, they share fields like username, password .... so you can combine them into one table and may be add a field call type to differentiate them. Create Employee class and Customer class which inherit from users tables. User table should have an integer field address_id, and Addresses table should have an integer field state_id.

user.rb should have this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  ...
end
```

customer.rb

```
class Customer < User
....
end
```

address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :state
 ...
end
```

state.rb

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
   ....
end
```

Now you can call something like this:
 `@customer.addresses.first.state_id or @customer.addresses.first.state.name`

Do the same thing for employee.

When you want to find employee that has the same state as current customer.

```
@current_state_id = @customer.addresses.first.state_id (#or state_id of default address)

@employees = Employee.joins(:addresses).where("addresses.state_id = ?", @current_state_id)
```